# GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20Blob] 404 (Not Found) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I don't know but I can't recover image from Rest API; Please helpe me!

private baseUrl:string= "http://localhost:8080/";

Service:

```
public downloadeImageEcho1( id:number): Observable<any>{
  
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/downloadFile/"+id, { responseType: 'blob'});
```

}

component.ts:

```
getImage(id:number){
  this.serviceDossier.downloadeImageEcho1(id)
  .subscribe((data :any)=>{
    this.imageEcho=data;
    console.log(this.imageEcho); 
  })
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf = imageEcho>
            <img [attr.src]="imageEcho">
            
          </div>
```

error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX6GW.png)

thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to set the image src to the URL of the image instead of fetching the image through the HTTP Client.

`[attr.src]="imageEcho"`

is causing the additional http request to occur.

Comment: thank... 
I don't understand .... please explain a little!

Comment: From what you've shown, you need to do something like this: <img [src]="this.baseUrl+'/downloadFile/'+id"